# What caused the "Fatal error in ccfe" compilation error in the Solaris C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, solaris, compilation, compiler-errors

I got this error message from the C++ compiler:

> CC: Fatal error in ccfe: Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

What could cause it?

Comment: What's the question? Can you isolate the code that it's having trouble with?

Comment: Hmm... If you can phrase this as a question, and add enough specificity to allow someone else with the same problem to find it, this could be useful...

Comment: My original question was: 
"C++ compiler crashes for no apparent reason"
"In my case I got: CC: Fatal error in ccfe: Segmentation Fault (core dumped)"

I now what this means: The compiler got SIGSEGV. Now, the question is WHY it did. A posibiliy is a bug in the compiler, but in mails with the people at SUN we discovered that the answer is the name of this site: it was a memory request failure for stack due an establised user limitation for it.

The edit made for this question is INCORRECT and this is a very important problem of this site, which discourages me for posting again.

Comment: Again: I know perfectly what "CC: Fatal error in ccfe: Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" means.

Comment: @chila: i think i see where the confusion arose... Please see my edit.

Comment: Much better man, but I think it should instead be "What caused the segmentation fault int the Solaris C++ compiler". I know what caused the "fatal error in ccfe", it was the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My user stack limit was very low (1MB). Since the compiler is heavily recursive, this limit as not enough. In solaris, the command for diplaying and changing this limit is ulimt. Other memory limits (virtual, heap) could cause this too.

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5389815&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is not likely to be a long-term useful resource.  Now that the original user has had their issue addressed, perhaps this question should retired. (deleted?)
Otherwise someone should extract information from the forum posting and summarize it here in a way that's generally useful to people.